# Building a ferrous metal detector

Tags: proximity-sensor, hall-effect, metal-detector

I'm planning to build a ferrous metal proximity sensor to use as part of a robotics project. During my research, I found a very helpful youtube video ([linked here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wyeogsahag&t=189s)) that shows how to do so for a Hall effect sensor (OH49E) that runs on a 5 V battery. As my project will be run using an 11 V battery, would it be possible to merely substitute a different Hall effect sensor with a higher input voltage range (such as [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5053.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1695341624403&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fdrv5053))? Is there a reason why this would be a bad idea that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't use the DRV5053 you linked here if both of your Hall effect sensors are the same. However, you do have some other options:

### 1- Adjusting the voltage to 5 V

You can use a voltage regulator like the LM7805 to bring your battery's voltage down to 5 V. It is super simple, basically 11 V in, 5 V out. It might generate a little bit of heat though, and run your battery down faster due to the "lost volts".

Another method (probably the simplest), is you can create a potential divider from 11 V to GND with two resistors of equal resistances (probably about 1 kΩ to 5 kΩ) and use the 5.5 V in the middle for your sensors.

### 2- Plug it in and hope for the best

This method is not recommended, but if you want to try it, here it is. According to the spec [here](https://ohhallsensor.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/OH49E-OH49E-S-Hall-effect-linear-IC.pdf) the OH49E has a maximum input voltage of 10 V. 11 V is not that much higher than this, so it's likely you may burn out your sensors.

Comment: _”potential divider from 11 V to GND with two resistors of equal resistances (probably about 1 kΩ to 5 kΩ) and use the 5.5 V in the middle for your sensors.”_ The sensor uses 4.2 mA so it would drop 21 V across the top resistor (5 kohm). This won’t work. A voltage regulator is the way to go.